# Is it possible to ORDER a parent table based on a CHILD table in SQL- PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data

Is it even possible to Order the Parent Table by the Child table? 
Say I have person_ID (from the parent table) that person_ID would receive many votes in the child table. So many votes can be in the child table for one person_id in the parent table. The votes can be +1 or -1. So if person_ID=001 receives 5 x (+1 votes) and 2 x (-1 votes). person_ID=001 would have a total score of +3. And lets say person_ID=002 had 3 x (-1) votes. Person_ID=002 would have an score of -3. Person_ID=003 has a score of 0.

Now lets say I want to ORDER the Parent table by the total score from the child table.

I know how to sum the Child table, but now I need to order the parent table based on the results of the child table.

```
  SELECT
  parent_id2,
  SUM (votes) AS total
  FROM childtbl GROUP BY parent_id2
  ORDER BY total DESC
```

I want the query result to look like below

Person_ID 001 | +3

Person_ID 003 | 0

Person_ID 002 | -3

Here is a link to SQL Fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ea694/6

Here is the code if it gets messed up

```
CREATE TABLE parenttbl
(
    parent_id integer,
    test character(25),
    test2 character(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (parent_id)
);

INSERT INTO parenttbl (parent_id, test, test2) VALUES (1,'adam','test'), (2,'steven','test'), (3, 'bob','test');

CREATE TABLE childtbl
(
    child_id integer,
    parent_id2 integer,
    votes integer,
   PRIMARY KEY (child_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_id2)
       REFERENCES parenttbl (parent_id) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE NO ACTION
       ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

INSERT INTO childtbl (child_id, parent_id2, votes) VALUES (1,1,1), (2,1,1), (3, 1, 1),(4,1,-1), (5,2,1), (6, 2, 1),(7,3,-1), (8,3,-1), (9, 3, -1),(10, 1, 1),(11,3,1),(12,3,1),(13,3,1)
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you just need to `left join`, aggregate, and sort:

```
SELECT p.parent_id, COALESCE(SUM(c.votes), 0) total_votes
FROM parenttbl p
LEFT JOIN childtbl c ON c.parent_id2 = p.parent_id
GROUP BY p.parent_id
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
```

The `left join` allows parents without a vote, in which case `COALESCE(SUM(c.votes), 0)` gives `0`.

You might also want to pre-aggregate the child table, so you don't need to aggregate in the outer query - this makes it seemless to return more columns from the parent table (whereas in the former query, you need to add each column to the `group by` clause):

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(c.votes, 0) total_votes
FROM parenttbl p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parent_id2, SUM(votes) votes FROM childtbl GROUP BY parent_id2
) c ON c.parent_id2 = p.parent_id
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Thank works! Also would there be a way to get the score some how to show in the query as well, like the sum total of c.votes?

Comment: Sick man! that's awesome. Is this a complicated Query or pretty easy for you ? I'm just learning.